# setting a minLength to a field only when a checkbox has been checked using the jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins, validation

I'm using this jquery [validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).  I would like to set a minLength property of 5 to a field only when a checkbox is selected.  I understand the "depends", but how do I use it along with a value of 5.

```
 "txt-alt-zip": {
            required: {                                                             // the zip is required if the alternate billing address is checked
                depends: function (element) {
                    return $("#chk-alt-billing-address").attr("checked");
                }

            },
            minlength: {                                                             // the zip is required if the alternate billing address is checked
                depends: function (element) {
                    return $("#chk-alt-billing-address").attr("checked");
                }

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here you go

```
'txt-alt-zip': {
  minlength: {
    param: 4,
    depends: '#chk-alt-billing-address:checked'
  }
}
```

Note that You can do it with any type of validation rules.

Answer (score 1):

From your request, this makes more sense to me:

```
 "txt-alt-zip": {
   minlength: function() {
     $result = 0;
     if ($("#chk-alt-billing-address").attr("checked")) $result = 4;
     return $result;
   }
 }
```